# InfluxDB and relational metadata?

Tags: nosql, time-series, influxdb

I am currently working on a project with InfluxDB, where I have to track and store several measurements. My issue: For all my measurement I also need to store some additional relational metadata (for reporting), which only change once or twice a week. Moreover I have some config data, for my applications..

So my question: Do you have any suggestions or experience with storing time-series and relational data like that? Should I try to store everything (even the relational data) within the InfluxDB or should I use an external relational DB for that?

Looking forward to your help!

Marko

Comment: InfluxDB is strongly optimized to work as a time series database and misses many features of structured SQL databases and feature related NoSQL databases. More or less your question depends in my opinion on the aim and the frequencies of your purpose. E.g.: in case your time series data are related to a primary key and the dependend metadata in my opinion it's clear: InlfuxDB in combination with a SQL db.